# page redirection problem inPython webapp

Tags: python, web-applications

I am trying to use the following command:

```
self.redirect('/sign/')
```

and i have already defined

```
appl = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/upload/',View),('/sign/',Next)],debug=True)
```

But the above command does not redirect me to corresponding page instead it displays the message

```
Status: 302 Moved Temporarily
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Cache-Control: no-cache
Location: http://localhost:8080/sign/
Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

Can anyone tell me what should I do?

Comment: That looks like a redirect to me... how isn't it a redirect to you?

Comment: I want to see the page that i used in redirection.